# Linux: Delay between regular expression executions? / Readings every file in directory?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have a directory on a linux machine that has hundreds of files. They are relatively short files and can easily be displayed and read in a command line in a second or two. Is there a way to print all of the files to the command line in an automated way, similar to typing "cat *" but with a one or two second delay between each print so that I can read each of the files?
I have tried making a bash script with:

```
cat $1 
sleep 2
```

And then calling "bash script.sh *" but it only prints one of the files and then stops.
Any suggestions?

Comment: try `for i in *; do cat $i; sleep 2; done`

Comment: `*` in a shell is used for globbing, not regular expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a loop in the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for f
do
  cat "$f"
 sleep 2 
done
```

Comment: When you're looping over the positional parameters you don't need the `in "$@"`, `for f; do` works.

Comment: @Kevin, good point, incorporated

Answer (score 0):

In your shell prompt (provided it's `sh`-compatible - most likely):

```
for i in *; do
   cat $i
   sleep 2
done
```

perhaps ? Loops over all the files (`*`) and `cat`s each one out. You don't really need a separate shell script for something so simple.

Comment: Double quotes around `$i` avoids problems with file names containing blanks, tabs, newlines and other exotic characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
while [ -e "$1" ]
do
  cat "$1"
  shift 1
  sleep 2
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in $(find /path/to/files -type f -name \*.\*); do
  cat $i;
  sleep 2;
done
```

This should work fine:

```
find /path/to/files -type f
```

if there is a specific extension you wish to focus on for eg then try something like this:

```
find /path/to/files -type f -name \*.cfg
```

and rather than looping you could do it all within find

```
find /path/to/files -type f -name \*.cfg  -print -exec cat {} \; -exec sleep 2 \;
```

Edited to add Kevin is not off his head I had commented that cat * might not work in a large folder containing lots of files and he responded to my comment which I had removed whilst he was writing his comment :)

Comment: `cat *` might not work but `for i in *` will. And it's whitespace safe.

Comment: check my updated answer why loop it when find can cat and sleep all in one